# Errors about imports Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have some problems with imports and my file structure.
I have created custom packages that are called in my script components.
I would like to use "import" "from" but my packages are not available.

Here is my tree structure :

```
|- __init__.py
|- main.py
|- project/
    |- __init__.py
    |- components/
        |- __init__.py
        |- packages/
            |- __init__.py
            |- HERE MY PACKAGES pkg_insert_bdd.py
        |- scripts
            |- __init__.py
            |- HERE MY SCRIPTS -> import pkg_insert_bdd
```

All scripts are executed in the main.py
But the problem is when a script is executed it can't find the package.

```
# my_script in folder scripts
from project.components.packages.pkg_insert_bdd import Database
```

This piece of code is present in my script.

Here is the result returned by Python :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

Do you have any ideas about my error? 
Or recommendations on the tree structure I use?

Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: If you're effectively running `main.py` and importing exactly with `from project.components.packages.pkg_insert_bdd import Database`, then it should definitely work

Comment: Can you post the contents of the root `__init__.py` file?

Comment: @corn3lius There's nothing in my __init__.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot import a module inside it.

This is why it doesn't work because you are trying to import the `project` module from the `scripts` folder, which is inside that module.

To solve this you need to move `scripts` folder from the `project` module and put it in the same directory as `main.py` this way Python will successfully import the module.

**UPDATE :**

If you want to test each script separately, then you will have to create a module called `tests` alongside `main.py`. This how the file tree should look like :

```
|- __init__.py
|- main.py
|- tests
    |- __init__.py
    |- test_script1.py
    |- test_script2.py
    |- ....
|- scripts
    |- __init__.py
    |- script1.py
    |- script2.py
    |- ....
|- project/
    |- __init__.py
    |- components/
        |- __init__.py
        |- packages/
            |- __init__.py
            |- HERE MY PACKAGES pkg_insert_bdd.py
```

Comment: But the principle of my tree structure is no longer respected?

Comment: Actually it is. In fact scripts should be independent from the module itself. You can take a look at https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/#scripts-vs-modules

Comment: Thank you very much for the documentation!
But I have a question about that, can we say that my script is a module of my main.py? 
And regarding the insert_bdd module should it be at the same level as my scripts executed by the main.py?

Comment: `main.py` is a file where you import the module and test it. You have 2 options : either put the code from `scripts` in `main.py` and delete `scripts` or put the code from `main.py` in `scripts` and delete `main.py`.

Comment: I can't delete either because the hand is used to execute all my scripts (currently I have 25 scripts) compared to the arguments I give to the main.py

I have to separate my main.py | my scripts | my modules

If my tree structure is like that: 

- main.py 
- modules/ 
   - all my modules.py
-scripts/ 
    - first_folder_scripts/
    - second_folder_scripts/
    - third_folder_scripts/
    - fourth_folder_scripts/

Do you think it's better? 
My scripts are divided into 4 categories, so you have to use several folders.

Answer (score 1):

Few Questions:
1) How and where are you executing your script? 
2) Are you executing it as a module or as a standalone script?

If you are executing your script as:

```py
python3 -m main
```

in your outermost directory

and still getting an error, try the following:

1) In terminal type the following before running the script:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:path_to_your_project/project_name
```

2) Then run:

```
python3 -m main
```

Comment: Additional Note: You can get `path_to_your_project` by typing ```pwd``` in terminal

Comment: In my main.py depending on the past arguments I execute my script present in the scripts/ folder

But the script in the script/ folder needs the package in the package/ folder to work. 

Am I clear about this?

Comment: How are you running the script from the scripts folder? Are you importing the class or script into ```main.py```?? Or are you running the script from the ```scripts/``` folder?

Comment: I execute the script via the module os.system() in the main.py

Comment: @p0lux it will not work because you can't import a module inside it. Take a look at my answer for details

Comment: I believe its a path (absolute vs relative import) issue here. Your ```scripts/``` folder and ```packages/``` should be able to live under the same directory. How are you importing packages into your ```some_script.py```? ```import package``` vs. ```import project.component.packages```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using pycharm,
kindly place the above code in the same structure in a folder name eg: bdd_framework. Open the project in pycharm and right click on the folder(bdd_framework) -> select "Mark as Directory as" -> "Sources Root".
This will resolve the issue.